# Bounded Context for EF 5.0 and Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern

I built an EF 5.0 repository pattern. Below is the context, repository and unit test.

My Question here is regarding Bounded Context. Entities A and B are part of the ABContext but Entity C is not part of ABContext. Now when I run the test to get entities on ABContext, I get the results back for all the three entities (T = A, B, C) `GetAll<T>` on ABContext.

I would expect "clist" to fail or throw an exception for entity C as `context.Set<T>();` does not exist for ABContext for T = C.

BTW.. entity C is part of a different context.

Context:

```
public class ABContext : BaseContext<ABContext>
{
    public DbSet<A> As{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs{ get; set; }
}

public class BaseContext<TContext>: DbContext where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected BaseContext()
            : base("name=DBEntities")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository : IRepository
{
    protected BaseRepository()
    {
    }

    public DbContext context { get; set; }        

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>() where T: class
    {
        return context.Set<T>();
    }
}

public class ABRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public ABRepository()
    {
        this.context = new ABContext();
    }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetAllTests()
{
    using (var repo = new ABRepository())
    {
        List<A> alist = repo.GetAll<A>().ToList();
        List<B> blist = repo.GetAll<B>().ToList();
        List<C> clist = repo.GetAll<C>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this is a little different than how I would usually do this and I can't test this out right at this moment so I apologize in advance if there's any errors here.

`BaseRepository.GetAll` calls `Set<T>` on `DbContext`. That method will create the `DbSet` of `T` and is the reason why `GetAll<C>` will return a `DbSet` and pass your test. You could even omit the `DbSet` properties for `A` and `B` and your test would still pass. Instead of relying on `DbContext.Set<T>` you should override and control the creation of `DbSets`. I usually use a `Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>` and override `Set` to return from said dictionary:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> _dbSets;

    public MyContext() : base(nameOrConString) {
        _dbSets = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> {
            {typeof (A), () => base.Set<A>()},
            {typeof (B), () => base.Set<B>()}
        };
    }

    public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() {
        if (!_dbSets.ContainsKey(typeof (TEntity)))
            return null; // or throw exception or whatever

        return _dbSets[typeof (TEntity)]() as DbSet<TEntity>;
    }
}
```

Now `Set` will only return the `DbSets` you've configured it to create/return.

Calling `MyContext.Set<A>()` will return a `DbSet<A>`.

Calling `MyContext.Set<B>()` will return a `DbSet<B>`.

Calling `MyContext.Set<C>()` will return `null` since it doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Comment: I tried implementing your solution and I am now facing a different issue related to generics. Its failing when I cast return obj to DBSet<TEntity>. Error says: The type TEntity must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter. I then tried to provide the reference to TEntity by putting "where TEntity : class" at the method, but then it complains that Constraints are inherited from the base method, so cannot be specified direcly. :(

Comment: Blah I was sure there would be at least one issue. Are you still extending your BaseContext?

Comment: Thanks for your help Smith!! I tried both ways. extending MyContext from DbContext directly and also extending MyContext from "BaseContext : DbContext". Either ways I am getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I noticed one mistake in my answer in that I used `_dbSets.Contains(...)` instead of `_dbSets.ContainsKey(...)`. Other than that, this works for me. I copied and pasted directly from the answer.

Comment: Yes I fixed that ContainsKey in my solution :). Are you not seeing the issue with generics that I am seeing?

Comment: I'm not. Tested it this morning. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/smith-neil/15c19f70a2f5acbb1df7) that I copy and pasted exactly from my project which works as expected. I will also say you're repository pattern is a little weird. Usually you wouldn't have an `ABRepository`. You'd have an `ARepo` and a `BRepo`. If you were to implement it that way you can just grab the `DbSet` property from your context since you know which set the repository needs. So there's other solutions that will work for you if you can change up your pattern a bit.

Comment: Its Weird!! How are you able to override DbContext Set<TEntity> method?? becos it is not marked as virtual, abstract or override. I am using EF 5.0 on .net 4.0 framework. I have created ABRepo so that I can work with all related entities in one context instance. otherwise I have to create around 50 repositories as i am dealing with 50 different entities. I referred this concept of bounded context from Plural sight julia lehrman course on EF in enterprise.

Comment: It's probably a version issue but I think I remember doing this with EF5. I'm on .NET 4.5 and EF 6.0. I'll try it out with EF5 in a few hours when I get home. I understand the reasoning behind a single repository. I used to use the generic repository pattern but eventually veered away from it. Most consider it an anti-pattern.